# Derived of template class not calling constructor

Tags: c++, templates, singleton

I'm implementing a Event template with C++ as below

Template.h

```
template<typename EventArg>
class Event {
public:
    typedef void (*EventHandle)(const EventArg&);
    vector<EventHandle> EventHandles;


protected:
    virtual void Init() { throw EventNotInitialized();};
    Event() 
    {
        printf("Event() \n");
        Init();
    }
};
```

Event.h

```
struct E_EventArgs {
    string data;
};
class E_Event : public Event<E_EventArgs>
{
public:
    static E_Event * Get() {
        static auto ins = new E_Event();
        return ins;
    }
protected:
    void Init() override {
        printf("E_Event() Init() \n");
    }
    E_Event() {
        Init();
        printf("E_Event() \n");
    }
};
```

Then I call `E_Event::Get()` to access to `E_Event`. But Here is the log:

```
Event()
```

I using arm-oe-linux-gnueabi-g++ (gcc version 6.4.0 (GCC))

Why constructor of `E_Event` is not called?

Comment: Why do you think the `E_Event` constructor is not called? (I believe you have jumped to an unwarranted conclusion.) Maybe the situation would be clearer if you replaced `throw EventNotInitialized();` with `printf("Event() Init() \n");`?

Comment: After you try that experiment, see [Calling virtual functions inside constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962132/calling-virtual-functions-inside-constructors).

Comment: The constructor is being called.  The question to you is this -- what version of `Init()` is being called in the constructor of `E_Event`?  Surprised?

Comment: @JaMiT you were right. The throw happen before the constructor call.

Comment: @Silver With this new insight (that the constructor of `E_Event` *is* called), can you write a more precise question that better represents the situation? *(Obligatory disclaimer, even though it seems unlikely to me: If editing this question would invalidate the current answer, the new version should be a new question.)*

Comment: @JaMiT I'm sorry, that I may misunderstand you. But I the situation is that the constructor of `E_Event` is never reach because I mistakenly throw an exception in its base class' constructor. There will be no question if constructor of `E_Event` is called.

Comment: @Silver: *"the situation is that the constructor of `E_Event` is never reach"* -- no, but you would be correct if you said that **the body** of the constructor of `E_Event` is never reached. What do you think is calling the constructor of `Event`? It doesn't happen out of thin air. The constructor of `Event` is being called by the constructor of `E_Event`, which you can see when you don't throw an exception. You could [make the call explicit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311625/what-is-the-importance-of-invoking-base-class-constructor-explicitly) if you want it even more clear.

Comment: Hmm... the answer to your question might lie in [Order of calling constructors/destructors in inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539282) or in a question marked as a duplicate of that, [why constructor of base class invokes first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45128900) *Note that in neither case is a template required. You could have removed this unnecessary complication from your question to help you better focus your question.*

Answer (score 3):

What you observe is not much of a consequence of calling a virtual function from a constructor.

> In a constructor, the virtual call mechanism is disabled because overriding from derived classes hasn’t yet happened. Objects are constructed from the base up, “base before derived”.

Which means when you call `Init()` from `E_Event`'s constructor, the most "recent" overridden version of `Init()` is of the base class `Event`.

However in your case the `Init()` call from `E_Event`'s constructor doesn't happen.

When you construct a derived class, an instance of base class is also constructed.
Consider this simple example.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
class Base
{
public:
    Base()
    {
        std::cout<<"Base constructor"<<std::endl;
    }
};
class Derived: public Base
{
public:
    Derived()
    {
        std::cout<<"Derived constructor";
    }
};
int main()
{
  Derived();
}
```

The output will be

```
Base constructor
Derived constructor
```

As you can see, the constructor of `Base` is also called.
So from `E_Event`'s constructor the `Event()` is also called, which already throws exception, that's why whatever will be in `E_Event` won't be called.

Comment: Not quite to the main problem. But thank for the quote. I haven't know that yet.